# Не видит модуль html2text

Tags: python, модули

Не видит модуль `html2text`. Установил через консоль `pip install html2text`

```
import requests
import html2text
site = requests.get('https://www.gismeteo.ru/weather-penza-4445/now/')
tt = html2text.HTML2TEXT().handle(site.text)
print(tt)
```

> `Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Htmltexttt.py",
>   line 2, in <module>
>       import html2text ImportError: No module named 'html2text'`

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @Twiss , консоль указывает путь к установленному модулю

Comment: Вы уверенны, что он этот пакет установлен?

Comment: @dedifferentiator Да

Comment: В Path Browser версия python указана 35-32, а модуль установлен в 36-32.

Answer (score 0):

Правильное название модуля `HTML2Text`, соответсвенно:

```
tt = html2text.HTML2Text().handle(site.text)
```

Comment: Выводит то же самое.

Comment: Ну тут уже дело не в модуле `HTML2Text`. Введите другой сайт, например https://www.stackoverflow.com